# Does Azure Service Bus Session guarantee the FIFO order?

Tags: azure, fifo, azure-servicebus-queues

The Azure documentation
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-azure-and-service-bus-queues-compared-contrasted
and different articles
https://jaliyaudagedara.blogspot.com/2021/04/azure-service-bus-handling-fifo-using.html
[How do you support FIFO message ordering with Azure Service Bus partitioned queues/topics?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28114288/how-do-you-support-fifo-message-ordering-with-azure-service-bus-partitioned-queu).
https://devblogs.microsoft.com/premier-developer/ordering-messages-in-azure-service-bus/.
https://connectedcircuits.blog/2020/03/19/ensuring-ordered-delivery-of-messages-using-azure-functions/.

are telling that Sessions can be used  to maintain FIFO order when there are multiple receivers listening to the same Queue.

However  [Don’t assume message ordering in Azure Service Bus](https://www.ben-morris.com/dont-assume-message-ordering-in-azure-service-bus/) article (written in 2014) and post  by the same author Ben Morris https://stackoverflow.com/a/29037645/52277
claims that **Sessions are not enough of a guarantee.**

> This isn’t enough to guarantee the order in which events are
> processed. For example, when a consumer reads a message using the
> default PeekLock mode it takes an exclusive lock for a set period of
> time. If this lock times out then the message is returned to the
> queue. This means it could be processed in the wrong order or even
> more than once.

It is sound like a valid concern.

Does it applicable for modern Azure Service Bus? If yes, what are workarounds?

Answer (score 3):

Azure Service bus queues that are having sessions enabled setting will be ensuring FIFO order processing for your messages. The current documentation has to be always referred as things keeps evolving. The current [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/message-sessions#first-in-first-out-fifo-pattern) clarifies in the below paragraph,

---

The session lock held by the session receiver is an umbrella for the message locks used by the peek-lock settlement mode. Only one receiver can have a lock on a session. A receiver may have many in-flight messages, but the `messages will be received in order`.

---

So, as long as your queue is session enabled, then automatically you can only send
messages with the `SessionId` property filled in, then you can be sure of FIFO processing.