# How can I get Azure Service Bus to work in a FIFO manner?

Tags: c#, azure, azureservicebus, azure-webjobs

We're not using topics for Azure Service Bus (Which I understand [has additional requirements to support ordering](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28702033/50447), and my understanding was that each queue should revert to operating in a FIFO manner; however, from analysing our logs just for today, we've had 384 of 15442 messages dequeued in a different order to when they were enqueued

To illustrate with an example, we had two messages, d4350a6e68ad4c9fb1fb9ccebd766590 and 0e19fbd29ffd4c4693fff6dd57e4f683; these were enqueued at 2018-11-14 09:27:31.8870000 and 2018-11-14 09:27:35.5950000 respectively (so 0e... was 4ish seconds later than d4...) However, they were dequeued at 2018-11-14 09:30:12.0320000 and 2018-11-14 09:29:57.4850000 respectively (so d4... was 15ish seconds later than 0e...). Over this timescale, we only had a single host active doing both enqueueing and dequeueing.

Whilst the timings on this are relatively close in human terms, we've seen

As I understood the queues to be, well, queues, I'm a little surprised that I'm seeing this behaviour - do I need to do any additional magic to ensure they are dequeued in the order they were enqueued?

For reference, the code that is enqueueing looks a little like:

```
var brokeredMessage = new BrokeredMessage(objectToQueue, new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(T)));            

var queueClient = QueueClient.CreateFromConnectionString(connectionString);
queueClient.RetryPolicy = new RetryExponential(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5), 5);
queueClient.Send(brokeredMessage);
```

And we're dequeueing with an Azure Webjob using a service bus trigger

Answer (score 1):

It is expected behavior. To ensure that the messages are processed in order, you should use [Sessions in Service Bus Queues](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/message-sessions).

This will allow you to process the messages in the sequence in which the messages are en-queued.

Comment: If I'm reading that correctly, that looks like I'll no longer be able to use a service bus trigger on the webjob?